# Rails 3 - will_paginate plugin - how to style it

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

Good evening,

I am struggling already longer time with the question, how to style with CSS link **Previous** and **Next**.
To my view I am including pagination this:

```
<%= will_paginate @articles, :page_links => false %>
```

So in the browser I will see the statement of database and under this statement 2 links - previous and next.
And I am trying to find a way, how to move with CSS the link **Previous** to the top and the link **Next** to the bottom, specifically:

### Instead

STATEMENT

PREVIOUS NEXT

### I would like to get

PREVIOUS

STATEMENT

NEXT

I tried to use google, but I found only the information about styling the links (color, font-weight etc.).

So I would like to ask you, if is something like above possible, and if anyone can help me, how to do...
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a CSS issue at all...

You should include twice the will_paginate toolbar, doing something like this in your template:

```
<%= will_paginate @articles, :page_links => false, :next_label => '' %> 
<!-- Your page content here, "STATEMENT" -->
<%= will_paginate @articles, :page_links => false, :previous_label => '' %>
```

I think this will do the trick!